# Power BI - Auto Refresh Embedded Tiles in Custom App

Tags: refresh, dashboard, powerbi

I have a Power BI dashboard with real-time input data from stream analytics. The tiles on dashboard refresh automatically in real time and show updated graphs/charts. This works just fine...

However, my requirement is to embed the tile/s in a custom app and I want them to be refreshed in real time. I am new to Power BI so before asking question, I tried to use the sample app code from github and successfully used it to embed a tile in the custom app from my dashboard. But unfortunately, the tile is static and it does not refresh like it does when viewed directly on the Power BI dashboard.

So, just want to confirm if it is possible to have the real time refresh functionality in custom apps for power bi tiles? If yes, how? or any work around to get this done please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and just got word from the Power BI team that embedding animated real-time tiles is not currently possible/supported but is on the roadmap as an enhancement. I will try to update this thread if I hear an update on this front.